# how to point root folder of DAM Display portlet programatically

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7

How to set one of the folders as root folder of Documents And Media Display portlet by programmatically.PFA image
[image]

Comment: I'd have a good pointer, but will wait until you acted on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Answer (score 1):

## Liferay Major Version

> Your question is tagged as **Liferay 6** and **Liferay 7**.  The two releases are drastically different.  This answer assumes you are using **Liferay 6.x** since you are asking about the DDM **portlet** as opposed to the **OSGI** module.

Programmatically setting that input resource to default as a folder of your choice requires you to create a JavaServer Page hook for a JSP in the *Document Library Display* portlet.  I am going to briefly explain how to create the JSP hook before getting into particulars.

---

## Create a Hook

[From Liferay's Knowledge base](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-a-hook-project-in-the-plugins-sdk#creating-a-hook-project-from-the-command-line)

> From your command line terminal, navigate to your Plugins SDK’s hooks folder. To create a hook project, you must execute the create script. Here’s the format to follow in executing the script:

```
create.[sh|bat] [project-name] "[Hook Display Name]"
```

> On Linux and Mac OS X, you’d enter a command similar to the one in this example:

```
./create.sh doc-lib-disp-hook "Document Library Display Hook"
```

> On Windows, you’d enter a command similar to the one in this example:

```
create.bat doc-lib-disp-hook "Document Library Display Hook"
```

> Liferay IDE’s New Project wizard and the create scripts generate hook projects in your Plugin SDK’s hooks folder. The Plugins SDK automatically appends “-hook” to your project name.

You will need to have Apache ANT installed for this to work.  Please reference the following documentation if you need to install it.

- https://www.mkyong.com/ant/how-to-install-apache-ant-on-windows/

Once the hook is created open it in your Liferay IDE or Liferay Developers Studio (or Eclipse).

1. In your IDE click the down arrow right below **File** (top left corner)
2. Choose **Liferay Plugin Project from Existing Source**
3. Double click on the **doc-lib-disp-hook** folder in your Plugin's SDK Hook directory to open.

You should see something similar to this (with  different name).

[image]

---

## Override JSP

Now that you have successfully created a hook plugin, we need to override the necessary file.  There are two files in particular that we need for this hook

- html/portlet/document_library_display/configuration.jsp
- html/portlet/document_library/init.jsp

> We need both files to logically walk through this example although we only need to actually override one of them.

To override the JSP's execute the following steps

1. Under your META-INF folder create a new directory called **custom_jsp**
2. Open up **liferay-hook.xml** in **Overview** mode
3. Click the Green Plus sign (to the right of Custom JSP label)
4. Search for both files listed above (copy and paste the URL into the window) then click save.

You will now notice you have the following directory structure.

[image]

Let's first open the **configuration.jsp**.  This is the code that produces the GUI you took a screen shot of.  Find the following code block.

```
        <aui:field-wrapper label="root-folder">
            <div class="input-append">
                <liferay-ui:input-resource id="rootFolderName" url="<%= rootFolderName %>" />

                <aui:button name="openFolderSelectorButton" value="select" />

                <%
                String taglibRemoveFolder = "Liferay.Util.removeFolderSelection('rootFolderId', 'rootFolderName', '" + renderResponse.getNamespace() + "');";
                %>

                <aui:button disabled="<%= rootFolderId <= 0 %>" name="removeFolderButton" onClick="<%= taglibRemoveFolder %>" value="remove" />
            </div>
        </aui:field-wrapper>
```

Inside that block you will see the Root Folder element you wish to set.

```
<liferay-ui:input-resource id="rootFolderName" url="<%= rootFolderName %>" />
```

As you can see the folder's url is already set by default to the variable **rootFolderName**.  We need to find where that variable is first initialized.

> We need not modify this file at all.  I had you include it and open it so you can follow through logically.

If you notice **rootFolderName** is not initialized anywhere in the **configuration.js**p file.  Therefore we need to investigate the **init.jsp** file because it is an include at the top of the page.  If you open that file you will notice the following block.

```
String portletResource = ParamUtil.getString(request, "portletResource");

if (layout.isTypeControlPanel()) {
    portletPreferences = PortletPreferencesLocalServiceUtil.getPreferences(themeDisplay.getCompanyId(), scopeGroupId, PortletKeys.PREFS_OWNER_TYPE_GROUP, 0, PortletKeys.DOCUMENT_LIBRARY, null);
}

long rootFolderId = PrefsParamUtil.getLong(portletPreferences, request, "rootFolderId", DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID);
String rootFolderName = StringPool.BLANK;

if (rootFolderId != DLFolderConstants.DEFAULT_PARENT_FOLDER_ID) {
    try {
        Folder rootFolder = DLAppLocalServiceUtil.getFolder(rootFolderId);

        rootFolderName = rootFolder.getName();
    }
    catch (NoSuchFolderException nsfe) {
    }
}
```

This code is basically saying we are going to initialize rootFolderName blank.  However if rootFolderId is set higher than 0 either by

1. Portlet preferences, or
2. Request Parameters

then we will set rootFolderName accordingly.

---

## Conclusion

If you want to set rootFolderName to a folder of your choice programmatically by default you can a few things.  The easiest thing to do would be to get the folder's id and modify the code like this

```
long folderIdConstant = 999999L; // place folder id here

long rootFolderId = PrefsParamUtil.getLong(portletPreferences, request, "rootFolderId", folderIdConstant );
```

That would set the default root folder programmatically.  Just build and deploy now.